# Datagridview get the total sum of a specific column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to grab all the values of a certain specific column in Datagridview **without any actual cell clicking or row selecting.**

I basically have 2 Datagridviews; **Order and Order Line.**

The Order Datagridview has a column named:

> Order Total

The Order Line Datagridview has a column named:

> Unit Price

I want to get the sum of the column Unit Price and transfer the total to the other datagridview in the column Order Total. Any idea on how to go about with this?

Edit: I used the compute method but got the error: `System.InvalidCastException: 'Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.'`

The code: I have a column named "unit_price"

```
int totalprice = Convert.ToInt32(line_dt.Compute(expression: "SUM(unit_price)", filter: string.Empty));
```

I have no idea what's causing this error.

Comment: If your grid is bound to a `DataTable` then call the `Compute` method of that table.

Comment: Yes, it's bound to a DataTable. I'll look into that.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I did the compute method but it would just give out an error:
System.InvalidCastException: 'Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.'

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fill up your orderline datatable 1st for that though (i.e. your orderline datatable must contain every line item

Loop through Order DataTable and find the Corresponding OrderLines in the OrderLine DataTable (Through the foreign keys)

Sum it up and update the values into the new column you created in Order DataGridView

Then use Row Filters, to change the orderline datagridview and obtain the filter foreign key from the order datagridview like this:

```
    private void dgvOrder_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             if (dgvOrder.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
             {
                 int selectedrowindex = dgvOrder.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

                 DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dgvOrder.Rows[selectedrowindex];  

                  string orderlineFilter = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["columnname"].Value);           


                 (dgvOrderLine.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Field = '{0}'", orderlineFilter);
             }
         }
```